# printing only the last 8 entries in a .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have an input csv file as below,I want to print only the most recent 8 entries..can anyone provide inputs on how to do this?

```
INPUT:-
trend.csv

['2013-06-25 20:01', '10']
['2013-06-25 20:06', '9']
['2013-06-25 20:06', '8']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '7']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '6']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '5']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '4']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '3']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '2']
['2013-06-26 20:08', '1']

OUTPUT:-
['2013-06-25 20:06', '8']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '7']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '6']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '5']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '4']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '3']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '2']
['2013-06-26 20:08', '1']
```

Code:

```
import csv
#Now read the recent 8 entries and print
cr = csv.reader(open("trend.csv","rb"))

for row in cr:  
    #print only the recent most 8 entries
    print row
```

Comment: Did you try storing 8 entries?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -  I would love to store only 8 entries ..bot sure how to do that though..any inputs?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - am getting an erro   File "database.py", line 17, in <module>
    last8 = collections.deque(maxlength=8)
TypeError: 'maxlength' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [tail recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-recipes) with a deque with n=8.

This creates a double ended queue where adding an item to the end (right) will efficiently pop off an item at the beginning (the left) to keep the length no more than max length:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> deque(range(10000),8)
deque([9992, 9993, 9994, 9995, 9996, 9997, 9998, 9999], maxlen=8)
```

The [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object is an iterator. Apply a limited-length deque to the csv reader and you are good to go:

```
import csv
from collections import deque

with open('/tmp/trend.csv','rb') as fin:
    deq=deque(csv.reader(fin),8)

for sub_list in deq:
    print sub_list
```

With your 10 line example, this prints:

```
['2013-06-25 20:06', '8']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '7']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '6']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '5']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '4']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '3']
['2013-06-26 20:06', '2']
['2013-06-26 20:08', '1']
```

Comment: Did you use exactly this code? `reader` is the csv object defined above. It is `cr` in your code...

Comment: +1 nice! But use `'rb'` for `open` with a `csv` (or `newline=''` in Python 3).

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Well on Unix -- `'rb'` is the same as `'r'` but `'rU` compensates for DOS/Windows/Mac line ending vs just a LF. I changed the CSV source file to LF so the Python code is more platform agnostic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

# Open the file with a "with" statement to provide automatic cleanup
# in case of exceptions.
with open("trend.csv","rb") as file:
    cr = csv.reader(file)
    lines = [row for row in cr]
# Use slice notation and the wonderful fact that python treats
# negative indices intelligently!
for line in lines[-8:]:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory/performance isn't an issue you could just do:

```
for row in list(cr)[-8:]:  
    print row
```